# Linear combination of basis function to represent a function

Tags: linear-algebra

I am struggling with understanding the concept of the basis function(spline) and I am not sure if I understand it correctly so far.

And I have two questions about it.

1.
As far as I understand, let's say I have 4 knots and the I have an interval [a,b], then I have 5 pieces of [a,b]

And I want to approximate the function V here.

Then, I can use 5 basis functions(g1 g2 g3 g4 g5) for each piece of [a,b] and approximate the function V.

I also heard that V can be written as a linear combination of basis functions.

Does this mean V = c1 * g1 + c2* g2 + c3 * g3 + c4 * g4 + c5 * g5? where c is a coefficient?

The reason why I keep confusing is that I thought each g should represent the function for each piece of [a,b]

For example, if g1 is x^3 + x^2, and this represents the first part of [a,b]. However, if I use g1 g2 g3 g4 g5 and make a linear combination(V), does V still have the same result as x^3 + x^2 for the first part of [a,b]?

2.
If I have 10 knots and want to use the degree of 3, how many functions(g) are required?

Does this depend on how many knots I have?

I think I should have 11 functions because I have 11 pieces of the interval.

But I am also confused because the degree is only 3 and since all the basis functions should be orthogonal, I am not sure whether it is possible to have 11 orthogonal basis functions of degree 3...

Comment: You seem to be thinking that a spline consists of separate functions on each piece, but this is not the case: you also need continuity of the function and continuity of its derivatives up to some order, depending on the context. What kind of "spline" are you considering?

Comment: Hello @angryavian, thanks for the comment. Sorry but I am confused right now. I thought the basic idea of this spline thing is to have separate functions on each piece and make them having same value for each knots and make continuous functions.  So are you saying this is not the case?? I am not sure what is your question actually... but I want to use cubic spline

Comment: @angryavian, https://www.psych.mcgill.ca/misc/fda/ex-basis-b1.html Figure 1 is the page where I thought approximation of order 3 spline is based on linking two different functions on the knot...